# Master equation for reproduction and mutual annihilation process

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

I was solving some exercises regarding the Master Equation and couldn't solve the following problem.

Consider a population with individuals $A$. This population can suffer the following processes:

i) Reproduction: $A \xrightarrow{\text{$\sigma$}} A + A$

ii) Mutual annihilation: $A + A \xrightarrow{\text{$\lambda$}} 0 $

where $\sigma$ and $\lambda$ are rates of evolution.

**My attempt**

I started by writing the transition rates $\omega_{n,n'}$ such as described in Reichl - A modern course in statistical physics, page 260. Hence, for process i) I got

$$\omega_{n,n+1} \Delta t = \sigma n \Delta t = \sigma_n \Delta t$$

while for the second

$$\omega_{n,n-2} \Delta t = \frac{1}{2} n(n-1) \lambda \Delta t = \lambda_n \Delta t $$

which yielded the master equation

$$\partial_{t}P(n,t) = -(\lambda_n+\sigma_n)P(n,t) + \sigma_{n-1}P(n-1,t) + \lambda_{n+2}P(n+2,t) $$

I was wondering: is this correct? I am unable to check this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching in several books, I found out that the expression is, indeed, correct. However, some authors prefer to absorve the $\frac{1}{2}$ in the definition of $\lambda$.

For future reference, after writing the Generating Function and simplifying, one should obtain

$$\partial_t \langle n(t) \rangle = \langle n(t) \rangle (\sigma + \lambda) - \lambda \langle n^2(t) \rangle$$

However, if absorving the factor as said above,

$$\partial_t \langle n(t) \rangle = \langle n(t) \rangle (\sigma + 2\lambda) - 2 \lambda \langle n^2(t) \rangle$$

This is practically the result we get by a qualitative analysis, in first order!